# How can I test a POST request directly using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, rspec-rails

I have defined permissions for my app using cancan.

However, I'd like a secondary test in place, i.e. not testing cancan's ability class directly, to ensure that a specified test user cannot perform a specific POST request.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I realize this might be a noob question, but can you point me to a url? an example?

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs should be sufficient. Basically, you just need to change the `get` in the spec, for `post`, and provide a bunch of attributes.

Comment: Very informative, thatnks. But I'm looking for information on how to post the request as a specified user.

Answer (score -1):

Read http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book - it contains everything you need to know.